# loopback remote method path definition issue

Tags: path, loopbackjs, loopback

I want to define a remote method with the following path:

http://localhost:3000/api/dataSourceTestings/{id}/a

```
In the dataSourceTesting.json file I defined its path as :
"http": [
        {
          "path": "/{id}/a",
          "verb": "put"
        },
]

But when I send request on this end point it gives me the error that can't found the method for this endpoint.
```

Do I need to define a relationship for it or is there any other way to define a remote method for this path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should define your remotemethod in dataSourceTesting.js file:

```
DataSourceTesting.remoteMethod('putDataSourceTestings', {
    accepts: [
        {arg: 'id', type: 'string'}],
    http: {path:'/:id/a', verb:'put'},
    returns: {arg: 'result', type: 'json'}
});
```

then implement your putDataSourceTestings function:

```
DataSourceTesting.putDataSourceTestings = function(id, cb){
    //your logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much :)

Answer (score 0):

A blog related to this issue:

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/remote-methods-in-loopback-creating-custom-endpoints/